# Support for HRT Music Streamer II

Tags: sound, usb

I'm considering a HRT Music Streamer II DAC (digital analog converter) for my HTPC. I run Ubuntu 10.10, but considering a upgrade to 11.04. Will this DAC be P'n'P, or at least easy to set up?

http://www.highresolutiontechnologies.com/support/ indicates its supported on Mac and Windows. Linux is not mentioned. All my searches seems to indicate that its a bit troublesome, but those are posts from 2009 and older.

Comment: I too did not find alot of newer topics for this. But in general if someone got it working (albeit troublesome) in 2009 it most likely will work easier (or with the same troubles) in newer version (that would be a regression and that's not normally good practice ;) ). Advice (basically the reason for this comment): I would start of with emailing them and asking if they know of people getting it working with Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

As nobody seems able to answer, I'll post the replay I got from High Resolution Technologies:

> "We have never generated any Linux support documents but have many consumers reporting no problems with a Ubuntu installation which includes a Streamer.  All Music Streamer models use only native audio class 1.0 drivers which are present in all modern operating systems including all flavors of Linux."

I'll update once I get my unit and get some results.

Edit:
After figuring out that the unit starts muted by default it was plug and play.

There is a small LED on the front telling signal-rate and such, and this was indicating mute. I selected the HRT in Pulseaudio, then muted and unmuted sound and it played perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I works almost flawlessly, as any generic usb-audio. The audio quality and sound level is good or v.good but it has a few features that are worth considering:

- It always stars muted, but is reported as unmuted to the system (mute and unmute to correct this)
- It has no in-build mixer so your on your own with digital mixer or your amp
- It only adepts 24bit audio streams - so you have to up-sample most mp3 and video